# Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery in vue js +laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

[image]

when I import javascript file , I get this error. I have tried many times

Comment: What have you tried? Are you using a boilerplate project? Did you ensure the right jQuery module is exported?  Could you post relevant code?

Comment: i user the jQuery came with the template , its a laravel project with vue js.

Comment: check with view-page-source. They are coming correctly or not.

Comment: Always post code and errors as text, not as pictures. Search engines can't index pictures. Nobody wants to retype your code to try it. Pictures are harder to read. See [ask].

Comment: ok i will do from the next time

Answer (score 1):

Ensure Bootstrap can access jQuery using `$`.

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

OR

```
import jquery from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.jQuery = jquery;
```